# Auto height for a foreignObject in SVG

Tags: svg

I have, in my SVG, a foreignObject which contains a p element. I want the height of this structure to be adapted to the height of my text.

The p element is already adapted : I've done nothing for that.

But I have troubles for the foreignObject. If I remove the field height, it doesn't work. height:auto doesn't work either.

Comment: If you could explain why you need the foreignObject to adapt that might help. Does it break anything if the foreignObject is larger than it needs to be?

Comment: The problem is that some objects will be covered by the foreignObject, and so it will be impossible to click on them for example. I could put the foreignObject before the other objects, but I want that the <p> is over the other objects, so I think that it is necessary to put all before. (z-index seems not work in Firefox)

Comment: Is it a requirement that the p elements are inside the svg? Is it possible to split it in two or more parts? E.g background svg, html elements, foreground svg, all layered with z-index. It would be easier if you had a simple example showing what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 27):

Since there is no real use of scaling up and down the `foreignObject` itself, then you can set both foreignObject `height` and `width` to `1`, and via CSS set `foreignObject { overflow: visible; }` to make its content visible whatever it is and do whatever you need to do it with it.

Comment: Does not work in Safari. I had to set height to "100%" in Safari, which makes the object overlap the other objects in all other browsers. But it's quite hacky and you cannot wrap the foreignObject in a g anymore.

Answer (score 11):

You can set height of the `foreignObject` element in `em` units, maybe that could help?

Right now the `width` and `height` attributes of a `foreignObject` are required, and must have values > 0, otherwise the element will not be rendered.

**Update:** An alternative is to just set the dimensions of the foreignObject to 100%, and use the fact that the foreignObject has a transparent background per default. Since other elements in svg are laid out in an absolute manner anyway they don't depend on the foreignObject size.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <style>
    p { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 100px; }
  </style>

  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="lightblue"/>

  <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        some wrapped text...
        some wrapped text...
        some wrapped text...
        some wrapped text...
    </p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: I would like that the height of the foreignObject depends on the size of the text. It is not always the same : I cannot predict it and give the correct height in em units.

Comment: You could also specify the foreignObject height as 100%, would that work? I assume then that a transparent background is used for the foreignObject itself.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, in this case the foreignObject takes all the screen height (from its starting point to the screen's bottom). I haven't understood the second part of your message.

Comment: Answer to your edit : yes but the problem is that some objects will be covered by the foreignObject, and so it will be impossible to click on them for example. I could put the foreignObject before the other objects, but I want that the <p> is over the other objects, so I think that it is necessary. (z-index seems not work in Firefox)

Comment: As I wrote in my answer above (I dont understand why is there -1, maybe someone can explain this to me?:). Set `height` and `width` to `1` and set `overflow: visible` and you are fixed.