# How to set height properly for HTML embedded inside an embedded SVG element

Tags: html, svg

The goal is to make the HTML embedded inside a SVG element occupy the full width and height of the root SVG element, which itself is embedded inside a HTML document.

However, as you can see from the Codepen, the width attribute seems to work, but the height attribute fails to affect the root SVG element. The embedded div is not 2688 pixels tall as a result.

Ultimately, the SVG root element and its contents should be 1242x2688.

What's wrong?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyJZbr

```html
<svg id="rootSVGBox" width="1242" height="2688" viewBox="0 0 1242 2688">
  <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
    <div id="testBox" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background:#00B9FC" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      Why is this height wrong?
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, your example works.
On a sidenote, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254651/auto-height-for-a-foreignobject-in-svg) offers a solution by absolutely positioning the div inside the svg element :

```css
#testBox {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<svg id="rootSVGBox" width="1242" height="2688" viewBox="0 0 1242 2688">
   <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
      <div id="testBox" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background:#00B9FC" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        This is 100% height.
      </div>
   </foreignObject>
</svg>
```